# What is the best way to implement this class in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class(let's call it `foo`) which contains 20 members. The class has a method 
`public foo Rotate(double angle)`.

This method rotates calling object with certain angle and creates a new `foo` object. 10 members of the new object is always the same as the calling object.

What is the best way to implement this class so that I don't have to recalculate all the 20 members every time the Rotate method is called?

Comment: It might be simpler and faster overall to recalculate all the members than it is to try and cache them.  It depends on how complex the calculations are.  Caching will add additional complexity, so you should probably make sure you actually need this.

Comment: @Vinit You're misusing that.. There's nothing to try here - he could obviously implement a constructor with 20 parameters, but he's asking if there's a more elegant way to do that. It's a perfectly valid question IMO.

Comment: The problems the Rotate method will be called many times and takes up a lot of time of the whole calculation

Comment: I don't quite understand the full purpose of the Rotate method - it rotates the object AND returns a new object?

Comment: Daniel You are right. Think about foo is composed of many shapes and every time it rotates generate a new foo

Comment: Another question: do the properties in your object have public setters? That is, can you change the members of your class outside of the class? For example, could you do shape.Area = 10 outside of the Shape class (or whatever your class is called)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you can change your class properties outside of the class, I think your best solution would be a [copy constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

What this essentially means is that you define a constructor in your class that takes an object of the same class as a parameter, then copies all of the object's properties into a new object.

Since all you're doing is assigning values, there's no problem with efficiency (assuming the values are primitives).

Then, once you've initialized the new object, set the 10 different properties to their rotated counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MemberwiseClone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx) to do a shallow copy of all your fields:

```
public class Foo
{
   public Foo Rotate(int angle)
   {
       var newInstance = (Foo)this.MemberwiseClone();
       // do other stuff...
       return newInstance; 
   }
}
```

If the 20 fields are value types then you should be set. If they are not then you are probably safer using a copy constructor.